# PHP exec command on Nginx

Tags: php, c, linux, gcc, nginx

I'm trying to compile a C program with shell_exec() (I tried using exec() also). I'm using nginx on CentOS 6 as a server. Here is the command I try to execute:

```
/usr/bin/gcc /MyStuff/program.c -o program
```

I set the permissions of the files and the parent folders to 755 and also tried:

```
/usr/sbin/setenforce Permissive
```

But none of them seems to give result. The php is under user apache. The output of the command execution when

```
/usr/sbin/setenforce Permissive
```

is:

```
collect2: cannot find 'ld'
```

When

```
 /usr/sbin/setenforce Enforcing
```

is

```
 cc1: error: /MyStuff/program.c: Permission denied
```

Any ideas what's the problem?

Comment: that's not a permissions error. either `ld` isn't in the path of whatever shell/user Apache's running as, or you don't have a complete toolchain installed and don't have a linker to begin wtih.

Comment: UPDATE: Thank you, the problem turned out to be something with compiling C programs, i rewrote it on perl and now it's working with no problems :).